# How configure Ganglia in Unicast correctly?

Tags: linux, monitoring, ganglia, gmond, gmetad

I'm working with Ganglia, great tool by the way!
I'm trying to make this [topology](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1FGKIowyQdG9hBTTiBWpSqrVdswTPg0ZON-qLvCC056s/edit?usp=sharing), with some nodes running `centOS 6.4`, `centOS 5.9`.

So for this I'm trying this configuration for GMetad (the rest is default):

```
##########################################################################
Head Monitor Cluster (GMetad + Gmond > mute no > deaf no + GWeb ) | centOS 6.4 (desktop)
##########################################################################
data_source "head monitor clusters" 10 192.168.1.100 # 192.168.1.100 == localhost
data_source "monitor cluster" 10 192.168.1.51:8649
gridname "Company"
authority "http://192.168.1.100/ganglia/"



##########################################################################
Monitor Cluster (GMond > mute no > deaf no ) | centOS 6.4 (minimal)
##########################################################################

globals {
  daemonize = yes
  setuid = yes
  user = ganglia
  debug_level = 0
  max_udp_msg_len = 1472
  mute = no
  deaf = no
  allow_extra_data = yes
  host_dmax = 86400 /*secs */
  cleanup_threshold = 300 /*secs */
  gexec = no
  send_metadata_interval = 5 /*secs */
}

cluster {
  name = "Monitor"
  owner = "unspecified"
  latlong = "unspecified"
  url = "unspecified"
}

/* The host section describes attributes of the host, like the location */
host {
  location = "unspecified"
}

udp_send_channel {
  host = 192.168.1.51 # send the data collect to itself
  port = 8649
  ttl = 1
}

udp_send_channel {
  host = 192.168.1.100 #send the data to 
  port = 8649
  ttl = 1
}


/* You can specify as many udp_recv_channels as you like as well. */
udp_recv_channel {
  port = 8649
}

/* You can specify as many tcp_accept_channels as you like to share
   an xml description of the state of the cluster */
tcp_accept_channel {
  port = 8649
}


##########################################################################
Node (Gmond > mute no > deaf yes ) | centOS 5.9 (minimal)
##########################################################################

/* This configuration is as close to 2.5.x default behavior as possible
   The values closely match ./gmond/metric.h definitions in 2.5.x */
globals {
  daemonize = yes
  setuid = yes
  user = ganglia
  debug_level = 0
  max_udp_msg_len = 1472
  mute = no
  deaf = yes
  host_dmax = 86400 /*secs */
  cleanup_threshold = 300 /*secs */
  gexec = no
}

cluster {
  name = "Monitor"
  owner = "unspecified"
  latlong = "unspecified"
  url = "unspecified"
}

/* The host section describes attributes of the host, like the location */
host {
  location = "unspecified"
}

/* Feel free to specify as many udp_send_channels as you like.  Gmond
   used to only support having a single channel */
udp_send_channel {
  host=192.168.1.51 #send to monitor cluster
  port = 8649
  ttl = 1
}

/* You can specify as many udp_recv_channels as you like as well. */
udp_recv_channel {
#  mcast_join = 239.2.11.71
  port = 8649
#  bind = 239.2.11.71
}

/* You can specify as many tcp_accept_channels as you like to share
   an xml description of the state of the cluster */
tcp_accept_channel {
  port = 8649
}
```

And that's it.
But this configuration it's not working, I already setup **9 virtual machines** to make this work out, but nothing so far.
I `disabled iptables, ip6tables and selinux`. I'm working on this for 3 day and night and nothing seems to work..
I would like some help in this, please, please, I beg for help. I really don't understand why this configuration ain't working, after read so many tutorials and O'Reilly book about Ganglia. Any idea ? Or help ?

And yes, if I do :
from 192.168.1.100 8649
`telnet 192.168.100 8649`, [the whole data collected is displayed](http://pastebin.com/NxrWPkEy).

The same thing to `192.168.1.51`, from `192.168.1.100`, but this one do not display in the Ganglia Web.
The charts, of it,  are always `-nan.`

Any idea ? Thank you!

Comment: what's 'gstat -a' on the gmetad instance return?  I had problems with Unicast initially by allowing TCP traffic on 8649 but not allowing UDP, but it sounds like you've disabled your firewall already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem.
For some reason `ganglia-gmond` that came with centOS 5.* is `gmond-3.0.7` which came with `EPEL` package, but I added `rpmforge` repository and could found out the version `3.1.7` which seems to support the unicast configuration, now everything is working fine.

Thank you!